# Serving Static File on Django

Tags: python, django, static

I have been trying to serve my static files at my Django project, however it cannot find or load it. I have tried different approaches, but none seems to fix the issue.

The static folder is in the same directory as the manage.py.

Also, I have installed the WitheNoise but it also did not solve the problem.

In addition: I am using docker, I have done the collect static and checked the container. All the files are correctly there.

**Django version = 2.0.1**

**Development environment**

Code Structure:

Project

```
- assets
- config
- docs
- project-root
- - static
- - manage.py
- - templates
- - apps
- - project-root
- - - settings.py
- - - urls.py
...
...
```

setting.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'pages.apps.PagesConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

html file

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/bootstrap.css" %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/jquery.bxslider.css" %}">
  <!-- Custom -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/animate.css" %}">

</head>
```

Let me know if there is anything else that I need to add to the post that will help you.
Thank you,

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/ and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/deployment/

Answer (score 0):

The version of Django is not mentioned in the question, also the environment - (production/development)

-In recent versions of python {% load static %} is recommended instead of `{% load staticfiles %}`

-If `Debug is True` and if `django.contrib.staticfiles` is not present in INSTALLED_APP -

-either add `django.contrib.staticfiles` to `INSTALLED_APP`
or
append `static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` to `urlpatterns` to serve the static files.

- Also for static files not in app folders the directory needs to be listed in STATICFILES_DIRS-

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    'any_other_locations',
]
```

Comment: I appreciate the help. But it did not fix the problem, it still not finding the files...I edited the question with more information regarding structure and version

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `settings.py` file and add WhiteNoise to the MIDDLEWARE list. The WhiteNoise middleware should be placed directly after the Django SecurityMiddleware (if you are using it) and before all other middleware.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
  #(Rest of the Middleware here)
]
```

Routes for the whitenoise cache and static files:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

And run the collectstatic

```
django-admin collectstatic
```

or

```
python3 manage.py collecstatic
```

If you want to run in inside the docker container, here is more info

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

More info about Whitenoise:

http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Even with the alterations, I still not able to find the files. The error persists...I edited my question with more information about versions and structure

Comment: Hmm, trying to remember what I have used to make it work on my project. Have you enabled Whitenoise also in `settings.py`? See at: [Enable Whitenoise Middleware](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#enable-whitenoise)